# There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate

Tags: .net, ssl, asp.net-core

I installed the dotnet-dev-certs v2.1.1 tool and it generates an error when trying to trust the certificate:

[image]

When I tried trusting it via the certificate manager, it returns this error:

[image]

Comment: I tried reinstalling visual studio and sdks but still didn't work. I ended up resetting my pc and re-running the command through visual studio's Package Manager Console, and it worked.. Might be some kind of certificate store issue or conflicts from multiple .net core sdk installation or something else..