# Why don't I have ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate?

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, https

I'm having trouble in that running my brand new ASP.NET Core app in that it fails to load the website when I run the debugger (see screenshot at the bottom of the question).

I have a hunch this is because of an issue with the certificate so I tried to trust the certificate with the following command:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

It errors:

> PM> dotnet dev-certs https --trust
>   Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
>   There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate.
>   PM> dotnet dev-certs https --check
>   A valid certificate was found.
>   PM>

There's a valid certificate but [checking certificates per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409783/475766), I don't see the certificate in Personal/Certificates or in Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates either.

I'm a little stumped on a resolution; this affects all my Core applications so I can't get any development done.

Why don't I have a certificate there and how can I rectify this?

[image]

Comment: Try `dotnet dev-certs https -v` for list the certificates.

Comment: Did you see the [popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550040/there-was-an-error-trusting-https-developer-certificate)?

Comment: @Rena I did once... It doesn't appear anymore

Comment: Have you tried running the terminal in admin mode?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to remove "old" certificates - check if you have more than one certificate installed (dotnet dev-certs https -v). If this is the case the following steps helped in my case.

- Finish Visual Studio
- Remove all certificates by calling dotnet dev-certs https --clean (command line admin mode)
- Create a new certificate by calling dotnet dev-certs https --trust
- Start Visual Studio again